# Call to a member function delete() on null Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

When i want to  delete a table of users it says Call to a member function delete() on null Laravel. why??

this is the code:

web routes:

```
//admin starts
Route::prefix('/a')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
    Route::get('/overzicht', 'AdminController@overzicht')->name('admin.overzicht');

    Route::get('/product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('product.add');
    Route::post('/product/create', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
    
    Route::get('/userlist', 'UsersController@list')->name('user.list');
    Route::delete('/userlist/{id}', 'UsersController@destroy')->name('userlist.destroy');
    Route::get('/userlist/{id}', 'UsersController@details')->name('user.details');
});
```

blade list:

```
<form class="form-group pull-right" action="{{ route('userlist.destroy', ['id' => $id->id])}}" method="post">
@method("DELETE")
@csrf
<button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" value="Delete" style="border: none"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

model:

```
 protected $table = 'users';
```

Contoller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
//   if ($id != null) {
//     $id->delete();
//     return redirect()->route('user.list');
// }
    $userr = Dum::find($id);
    $userr ->delete();
   session()->flash('message', 'Delete Successfully');
    return redirect()->route('user.list');
}
```

Comment: common sense.. its mean your ID is wrong.. you cant delete object which is null

Comment: This is happening because `Dum::find($id);` returns **null**. And you cant delete null. To get rid of this error, use `Dum::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: thank guys I am new with laravel. this is extremely helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make sure you got the model instance from your db:

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $userr = Dum::find($id);
    if( $userr==null)
     {
        session()->flash('message', 'Deletion failed');
     }
         else
     {
        $userr ->delete();
        session()->flash('message', 'Delete Successfully');
      }
   
    return redirect()->route('user.list');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I am still new with laravel

Comment: done thank you. i also new with stackoverflow ;)